# Check if string matches one of few regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if an IP address is private, without importing another module. I found these regexes which should do the job:

```
^127.\d{123}.\d{123}.\d{123}$
^10.\d{123}.\d{123}.\d{123}$
^192.168.\d{123}$
^172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{123}.[0-9]{123}$
```

My question is, what's the proper, efficient way to check if *either* of those regexes will match `my_str`? Is there a better way than four `if...elif`?

Comment: Do you just want to know if any of those matches, or do you want to know which one matches? You can or-join them together, use `any`, or a loop.

Comment: @tobias_k No I'm not looking for which ones matches. I'm just trying to determine if an IP address is from a private network

Answer (score 4):

You can use either `|.join` to concatenate the individual regular expressions to one big disjunction, or use the `any` function to test whether any of them matches.

Also note that the expressions seem to be wrong: `\d{123}` will match exactly 123 digits, *not* 1-3 digits! Also, the third one seems to be missing the fourth group of digits.

```
regexes = [r"^127.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$",
           r"^10.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$",
           r"^192.168.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$",
           r"^172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$"]

for ip in ips:
    if re.match('|'.join(regexes), ip):
        print "matching method 1", ip
    if any(re.match(r, ip) for r in regexes):
        print "matching method 2", ip
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regex alternation and combine them into a single regex:

```
^(127.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}|10.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}|192.168.\d{1,3}|172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})$
```

Comment: The approach is good, but I'm afraid, with those `\d{123}`, this won't match any IP...

Comment: Yes right, I didn't pay attention to OP's regex (assumed those were correct). Fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget about the much simpler, less fault-prone solutions of `ipaddress` and `IPy.IP`. Although `ipaddress` and `IPy.IP` are much slower than direct RegEx-testing, they do a great job and you do not have to "re-invent the wheel" all the time.
Additionally: Even when you test millions of IP addresses it just takes a couple of seconds with `ipaddress` and `IPy.IP`, so I would say the performance is not that big of a deal.

The only thing to keep in mind: `ipaddress` only works with Python >= 3.3, while `IPy.IP` works well with both, Python 2.X and Python 3.X.

I did some performance testing for you:

```
import timeit
import re
import random
import ipaddress      # works only in Python >= 3.3
from IPy import IP

someIPs = ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.1", "95.25.80.5", "91.25.36.4"]

regexes = [r"^127.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$",
           r"^10.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$",
           r"^192.168.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$",
           r"^172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}$"]

COUNT = 100000


def test1():
    return re.match('|'.join(regexes), random.choice(someIPs))


def test2():
    return any(re.match(regex, random.choice(someIPs)) for regex in regexes)


def test3():
    return re.match(r"^(127.\d{123}.\d{123}.\d{123}|10.\d{123}.\d{123}.\d{123}|192.168.\d{123}|172.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{123}.[0-9]{123})$", random.choice(someIPs))


def test4():
    return ipaddress.ip_address(random.choice(someIPs)).is_private


def test5():
    return IP(random.choice(someIPs)).iptype() == "PRIVATE"


print ("test1: " + str(timeit.timeit(lambda: test1(), number=COUNT)) + "s")
print ("test2: " + str(timeit.timeit(lambda: test2(), number=COUNT)) + "s")
print ("test3: " + str(timeit.timeit(lambda: test3(), number=COUNT)) + "s")
print ("test4: " + str(timeit.timeit(lambda: test4(), number=COUNT)) + "s")
print ("test5: " + str(timeit.timeit(lambda: test4(), number=COUNT)) + "s")
```

This prints the following results:

```
test1: 0.22282320600015737s
test2: 0.5939347200001066s
test3: 0.16346287899978051s
test4: 1.111706949999916s
test5: 1.1817043560002276s
```